# Replace SR Suntour remote speed lockout to normal knob

Tags: mountain-bike, suspension

My MTB has **[SR Suntour XCM 30](https://www.bikester.co.uk/sr-suntour-xcm-atb-suspension-fork-275-100mm-incl-rl-handlebar-switch-black-757393.html)** fork with Remote Speed Lockout system. I rarely use the lockout system but it is useful sometimes. I want to convert this remote lockout system to normal knob which can be turned using hand when needed. This will help to reduce cockpit clutter while keeping lockout as well.

Is there any way to replace remote lockout with normal knob on mentioned suspension model?

Comment: A quick browse on Suntour's web site seems to indicate that the remote lockout is a optional add-on accessory, and there are rotary knob kits available.

Comment: I don't know if anyone has tried to order parts from Suntour in the last three years. My local shop tried to order a  plastic cap for a fork stanchion for 2 months on my warranty claim.  They got zero response from Suntour . I agreed  for some accessory discount and a used cap. Has anyone had a more recent positive experience?  My experience is parts are mostly unavailable.